# Autolayout priorities for labels in uitableview cell

Tags: ios7, ios8, ios-autolayout

I have UItableview"s custom cell which contains three labels, one view on left and one image on right. I have set content hugging priorities for all labels as 1000 for vertical.
Horizontal hugging priorities are 750,751 and 752 for label 1, label 2 and label3 respectively.
Content Compression resistance is set 1000 for all labels.

Height constraint for label One is >=20. For other two labels it is >= 0 as they may or may not contain text.

1)Vertical space priority for Content View and top label is 1000. 2)Vertical space priority for top label and middle label is 1000 3)Vertical space priority for Middle Label and bottom label is 1000. 4.Vertical space priority for bottom label and content view is 999.

I have set number of lines to zero and line break to "word wrap" for all labels.

Issue I am facing is that 
1.bottom label is overlapping with separator when text is in two lines.
2.If I increase Vertical space priority for bottom label and content view to 1000, then it is asking to lower vertical compression resistance. As a result it compresses the label.

Autolayout is breaking low priority constraint to satisfy higher priority constraints and at the same time it is not allowing to have all higher priority constraints.

Please help me in assigning priorities.